# CQ5 ExtJs DateField state not maintained

Tags: extjs, aem

have written a custom multifield which has a DateField. The issue is that when I select a date and close the dialog after clicking on the OK and reopen the dialog the date loses its state and I have to select it again. Here is the code:

```
   var MMCCamCar = {};

MMCCamCar.SubdomainNewslistingWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.Hidden
     */
    hiddenField : null,

    headline:null,
    date:null,
    description:null,
    url:null,
    checkbox : null,
    emptyField:null,


    constructor : function(config) {
        config = config || {};
        var defaults = {
            "border" : true
        };
        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        MMCCamCar.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    // overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
    initComponent : function() {
        MMCCamCar.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

        this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
            name : this.name
        });
        this.add(this.hiddenField);


        this.headline = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel : "Headline",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.headline);

        this.date = new CQ.Ext.form.DateField({
            fieldLabel : "Date",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            editable: false,
            format: "d-M-y",
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.date);

        this.description = new CQ.Ext.form.TextArea({
            fieldLabel : "Description",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.description);


        this.url = new CQ.form.PathField({
            fieldLabel : "URL",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            rootPath : "/content/mercer",
            editable : true,
            width : 600,
            allowBlank : false,
            listeners : {
                dialogselect : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                },
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.url);

         this.checkbox =  new CQ.form.Selection({
             type:"checkbox",
             fieldLabel:"Link Target",
             options:displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainNewslisting(),
             listeners: {
                 selectionchanged: {
                     scope:this,
                     fn: this.updateHidden
                 }
             },
             optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider
         });

          this.add(this.checkbox);

        /**
         * Added a dummy Empty field to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception in the resultant array
         * Without this hidden field, the empty values will be not be added to the multifield list
         */
        this.emptyField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel: "Empty Field",
            width:200,
            maxLength: "30",
            defaultValue: "empty",
            hidden:true,
            value:"empty",
        });
        this.add(this.emptyField);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
    setValue : function(value) {

        var parts = value.split(/<#-@>/);
        console.log("displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainNewslisting#parts", parts);
        this.headline.setValue(parts[0]);
        this.date.setValue(parts[1]);
        this.description.setValue(parts[2]);
        this.url.setValue(parts[3]);
        this.checkbox.setValue(parts[4]);
        this.emptyField.setValue(parts[5]);


        this.hiddenField.setRawValue(value);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
    getValue : function() {
        return this.getRawValue();
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
    getRawValue : function() {
        return this.headline.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.date.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.description.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.url.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.checkbox.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.emptyField.getValue();
    },

    // private
    updateHidden : function() {
        this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
    }

});

function displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainNewslisting()
{
    return [{
        "text":"check to open link in new tab",
        "value":true

    }]
}

// register xtype
MMCCamCar.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.XTYPE = "subdomainNewslisting";
CQ.Ext.reg(MMCCamCar.SubdomainNewslistingWidget.XTYPE, MMCCamCar.SubdomainNewslistingWidget);
```

I also want to know what function gets called when the dialog box is opened. The idea is to try and override any such function and set the value into date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being, datefield was unable to parse the date that is being set. It needs a valid string that can be parsed as Date.

Try using CQ.form.DateTime instead of CQ.Ext.form.DateField, it would work. The code snippet would be as shown below.

```
this.date = new CQ.form.DateTime({
    fieldLabel : "Date",
    labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
    width : 600,
    allowBlank : false,
    editable: false,
    dateFormat: "d F Y",
    hideTime: true,
    listeners : {
        change : {
            scope : this,
            fn : this.updateHidden
        }
    }
});
this.add(this.date);
```

You can set hideTime to false/true(as shown above), based on whether you need to display the timefield or not respectively. You can check the other configurations available [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.form.DateTime)

Comment: Hey thanks for your input but I don't want time field along with date. Only date is what I need. Plus any idea what all formats I can for date I can use.

Comment: Updated the answer, currently the docs site is down. You can check it once it is up again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.Is it possible that I can input the date in 17 December 2014 format.Also, I would appreciate if you can guide me how can I learn ExtJs from CQ5 perspective.

Comment: I have updated the format, kindly note that the format property is now dateFormat. There is nothing as learning ExtJs from CQ5 perspective. If you learn ExtJs, then you can apply the same in CQ. The link to the docs i provided should guide you.